# Creating dynamic buttons in android

Tags: java, android, watson-assistant

I am working on Watson Conversation chatbot. I have been trying to implement the 'options' response type in my chatbot application. My problem is "Creating 'n' number of dynamic buttons in Android where n is the number of label names of options present in the backend(IBM Watson Conversation)"

I have been able to retrieve the label names in form of text. Now I have to put these label names in "clickable buttons". Such that when a user clicks on a button, a value is passed to the backend (Watson Conversation API).

This is how I am retrieving option(response type) from backend. Watson Conversation sends reply in form of JSON.

Label name retrieving code:

```
 str = response.getOutput().getGeneric().get(i).getResponseType();
JSONArray arrayOptions = new JSONArray(response.getOutput().getGeneric().get(i).getOptions());
            int j=0; //j is used to count the number of options
            while (j<arrayOptions.length()){
              final Message outMessage2 = new Message();
              outMessage2.setMessage(response.getOutput().getGeneric().get(i).getOptions().get(j).getLabel());
              outMessage2.setId("2");
              System.out.println(outMessage2);
              messageArrayList.add(outMessage2);
              j++;
            }
```

Comment: the above code snippet exists in a method private void sendMessage(). I need to pass this j variable to the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method which is of type protected

Comment: "I need to pass this j variable to the onCreate..." – No, you don't. Just create and add your buttons when that code completes. As for actually creating those buttons, there are hundreds of examples and suggested solutions for that already here on-site. Which ones did you try? What problems did you have in implementing them?

Comment: @Mike M.thanks for your reply. "just create and add your buttons when your code completes". Can you elaborate or provide me with a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve your problem

First create a LinearLayout Layout inside xml

```
                 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_dynamic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
```

After that, use below code

```
LinearLayout layout_dynamic =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_dynamic);

for (int i = 0; i < YOURARRAY.length(); i++) {
String label = <Button Name as You Like>;
 LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 childLayout.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
 Button btnName = new Button(getActivity());
 btnName.setLayoutParams(newTableLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

 childLayout.addView(btnName, 0);
 layout_dynamic.addView(childLayout);}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Where to use this "LinearLayout layout_dynamic " code?

Comment: Should I use it in onCreate(bundle savedInstance) method?

Comment: I need to use my 'j' variable in my code. 'j' counts the options in backend. Depending on 'j' value, those many dynamic buttons will be created.

Comment: @RahoolChatterjee - LinearLayout is layout on which you have to create dyanmic button, may be this is inside MainActivity.xml

Comment: Second inside for loop, from where you get dynamic button list

Comment: What is this method getactivity() you are using?

Comment: Even nowhere I am using a Table layout

Comment: getactivity() use in Fragment same as context or MainActivity.this